# Splice not removing all matching elements in array

Tags: javascript, splice

I want to remove every `1` in an array. The final answer should be:

```
[4, 0, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 11, 9, 9]
```

But I get:

```
[4, 0, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 3, 5, 11, 9, 9]
```

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    let myNumber =[1,4,0,5,1,2,6,1,1,7,3,5,11,9,1,9];
    for(i=0;i<myNumber.length;i++){
        if(myNumber[i]===1){
        myNumber.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    console.log(myNumber);

  </script>


  
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't this work, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Start at the end of the array and work your way back to the beginning: `for (let i = myNumber.length; i >= 0; --i) {`

Comment: it works.thanks.but i want to know what is the diffrence.whats wrong with my code?

Comment: @mohammadrezaFaramarzi Read the linked Q&A above.